# How to resume the aborted file request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I would like to add pause and resume for my file upload. To pause the uploading, i have called abort method as below

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.abort()
```

File paused as expected. But now i need to resume the paused file.

How can I achieve this. What all the steps to follow to to this?

Please suggest your ideas

**Note: To use resumable.js tus.io is not preferable.**

Comment: Abort means abort, not pause. Since you have cancelled pending XHR you only can start over new request. Note that mentioned resumable.js uses HTML5 File API by sending chunks of file thru [`Blob.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Methods) method, see [line 29](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/blob/master/resumable.js) of resumable.js

Comment: Hi @andy, i am confused how to achieve pause and resume the file upload. Can you please suggest any sample with source for file pause/resume

Comment: Not really, I do not like to reinvent the wheel, there are libraries doing that job and (if you take a look into resumable.js code) it is quite complex subject so "my own" implementation would take significant time to deliver, considering tests across browsers etc.